# Why are Mac files able to have multiple owners?

Tags: macos, permission, unix, file

Regarding Unix file permissions, which Macs use, why are Mac files in particular able to have multiple owners? For instance, you can view the "Get info" panel of a file, and under the Permissions section at the bottom, add another owner by clicking on the plus sign "+".

How does this work? I don't think vanilla Unix is able to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You are right, vanilla Unix doesn't support this. But there is this thing called ACL (Access Control Lists) which allows for a much more granular definition of access rights than the usual user/group/world rights. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list):

> Most of the Unix and Unix-like operating systems (e.g. Linux, BSD, or Solaris) support POSIX.1e ACLs, based on an early POSIX draft that was abandoned. Many of them, for example AIX, FreeBSD, Mac OS X beginning with version 10.4 ("Tiger"), or Solaris with ZFS filesystem, support NFSv4 ACLs, which are part of the NFSv4 standard.

By default every file only has the user/group/world rights

[image]

```
pse@Fourecks:~/Downloads$ ls -le UML_Plakat_8_2012_Web-Download_V1.pdf 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 pse  staff  4914537 Jun 21 09:56 UML_Plakat_8_2012_Web-Download_V1.pdf
```

If you now add an additional owner

[image]

Finder automatically creates a corresponding ACL entry for this:

```
pse@Fourecks:~/Downloads$ ls -le UML_Plakat_8_2012_Web-Download_V1.pdf 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 pse  staff  4914537 Jun 21 09:56 UML_Plakat_8_2012_Web-Download_V1.pdf
 0: user:jonnyenglish allow read,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity
```

You can also modify ACL entries directly from Terminal by using `chmod` (which gives you significantly more details to manipulate than the *Get Info* dialog in Finder). For details it's probably best to run `man chmod` in Terminal and read the *ACL MANIPULATION OPTIONS* section.

Comment: Perfect, although I would just add that you will struggle to find a modern Unix implementation that doesn't support this, it is very much standard it's just that it's a ball ache to administer at a command line level, and most people never need to be aware of it.

Comment: It's a pain to administer even with [GUIs](http://best-mac-tips.com/2013/05/12/app-change-acl-permissions-gui/) because you can shoot yourself in your foot quite fast.