# How do I remove multiple owners from a file/folder?

Tags: command-line, macos, permission, user-account, acl

While trying to set up MAMP/PHPStorm, I CHOWNed the OWNER of my Sites folder to _www from myUser. Since this did not resolve the problem I was experiencing, I attempted to `CHOWN myUser /Users/myUser/Documents/Sites`... which worked, except *Get Info* shows both as owners, and `ls -l` reports _www as the (primary?) owner. I could not modify the folder contents, even though myUser is one of the owners.

When I `ls -leO@` as suggested in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125212/mavericks-user-no-longer-owner-of-home-folder-and-content?rq=1), I see the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 31 _www  wheel  -  1054 Dec 5 12:38 Sites
  0: user:myUser allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,
  writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

I `sudo chown :staff Sites` thinking this will give myUser more clout, and then `sudo chown myUser: Sites` which works in removing _www, but I'm left with:

```
MacBook-Pro:Documents myUser$ ls -leO@
...
drwxr-xr-x+ 31 myUser  staff  -  1054 Dec 5 12:38 Sites
  0: user:myUser allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,
  writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
...
```

I've read the MAN page for CHMOD and ACL as suggested in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98297/why-are-mac-files-able-to-have-multiple-owners), and I've tried `chmod -a#0 Sites` and variations with no success. How do I remove the ACL/xattr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chmod from Terminal is the way that worked. What I was doing wrong was a simple spacing error. Compare the code below (which worked) to the code I listed last in my question.

```
chmod -a# 0 Sites
```

If I read the MAN page correctly, I issued the command [`chmod`] to remove an explicit-numbered ACL [`-a#`] being number zero [`0`] from the directory Sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it from Terminal, but you could use a tool like BatChmod to redo the file permissions (and clear ACLs). 
http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/